# Редактирование контента на Django

Tags: django, контент

Сайт на Python, Django.
Каким образом можно отредактировать контент? Мне нужно изменить цену, а также описание, которое открывается по кнопке "подробнее". Где вообще их найти? Код со скрина я приложил из файла index.html. Долго копался но больше никаких файлов где бы было упоминание о ценах или подробнее не нашел.

Скриншот: [image: Скриншот]

Код:

```
<!------------------------------------Услуги------------------------------->
    <section class="services pt-5 pb-5">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-12 text-center">
                    <h3 class="mb-md-5">Услуги</h3>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row text-center d-flex flex-row justify-content-center">
                {% for item in category %}
                    <div class="d-flex  align-items-stretch">
                        <div class="services-item">
                            <div class="services-title border-bottom"><span>{{ item.name }}</span></div>
                            <div class="services-body">
                                <img src="{{ item.foto.url }}" alt="">
                            </div>
                            <div class="services-footer border-top d-flex justify-content-around">
                                <span>от {{ item.prise }} Р</span>
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-dark" data-toggle="modal"
                                        data-target="#modal-{{ item.id }}" type="button">Подробнее
                                </button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                {% endfor %}
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
    <hr>
```

Comment: [Пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12119/#12120)

Comment: @wchistow принял, код отредактировал и вставил без картинки.

Comment: цена товара в БД: {{ item.prise }}. Через админку пробовали? как правило разработчики делают доступным редактирование через панель.

Comment: @rpe4ka722 через админку был бы рад, но фрилансер который делал сайт пропал и единственное что оставил это послание делать суперюзера. А я когда его пытался делать у меня вообще сайт упал на пол часа, видимо что-то не так делал. Поэтому всячески ищу пути редактирования на подобии как главную страницу через правку кода index.html (( Но наверное такое с контентом уже не прокатит?
Вопрос, как то в БД можно попасть без создания суперюзера и можно ли туда суваться без риска положить весь сайт? Я просто в этом пока что слаб)

Comment: Лично я для начала сначала учусь писать код без опечаток. (Пожалуйста, не принимайте это как оскорбление)

Comment: @PeterKolosov 1) где тут опечатка? 2) код не я писал, сайт мне достался, в pyth я почти не соображаю, да и не стремлюсь изучить его. Главное просто решить задачу, достаточно простую, но на которую нет ответа. Может вы знаете, раз решили заглянуть сюда?

Comment: Может кто-нибудь хотя бы подсказать в какую сторону смотреть? Нужен ли суперзер если нет данных от админки? Какие есть решения?
Спасибо.